# How to acquire input devices in directx

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm learning DirectX by Frank Luna's 9.0c book and I'm having some troubles acquiring mouse and keyboard.

Here is the function that handles the initialization, by Frank Luna:

```
DirectInput::DirectInput(DWORD keyboardCoopFlags, DWORD mouseCoopFlags)
{
    ZeroMemory(mKeyboardState, sizeof(mKeyboardState));
    ZeroMemory(&mMouseState, sizeof(mMouseState));

    HR(DirectInput8Create(gd3dApp->getAppInst(), DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, 
        IID_IDirectInput8, (void**)&mDInput, 0));

    HR(mDInput->CreateDevice(GUID_SysKeyboard, &mKeyboard, 0));
    HR(mKeyboard->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIKeyboard));
    HR(mKeyboard->SetCooperativeLevel(gd3dApp->getMainWnd(), keyboardCoopFlags));
     -> HR(mKeyboard->Acquire());

    HR(mDInput->CreateDevice(GUID_SysMouse, &mMouse, 0));
    HR(mMouse->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIMouse2));
    HR(mMouse->SetCooperativeLevel(gd3dApp->getMainWnd(), mouseCoopFlags));
    HR(mMouse->Acquire());
}
```

an instance is created like so:

```
DirectInput di(DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE|DISCL_FOREGROUND,DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE|DISCL_FOREGROUND);
```

HR is a macro that calls DTrace when errors occur, so you may assume it does nothing.
This works fine most of the times, except for one situation: when I click on some other window while the App is being launched, it crashes while creating the mouse device. I pointed out the line where the problem occurs.

How can I modify this function so that it doesn't crash?

EDIT: Looks like it doesn't crash when I delete the macro on the "->Acquire()" lines. I believe the macro was being over sensitive to the error, so yeah :D

Comment: Perhaps have the application loop (call something like `Sleep(100);` in the mean time) and keep trying until it finally acquires the mouse. You could probably assume it will work when the window is 'focused' and use that as your wait criterion, but technically it could still fail so I'd recommend just constantly re-attempting to get the mouse.

Comment: That seems to work, but it implies that I can't have all the initialization code in one place (I would have to load devices at run time) or that I can't move on and do other things while the mouse is not acquired... If there was a way to create the device for the mouse without focus, that would be perfect.

Comment: In short: Don't. DInput mouse and keyboard was a useful technology in the days of Windows 95/98/ME, but as of Windows XP or later it's all a pile of hacks built on top of Win32 messages. Instead, cut out the middle-man of strange behavior and just use Win32 [mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645601.aspx) & [keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530.aspx) messages. For Windows 8.x consider ``WM_POINTER``. For high-resolution mouse, see ``WM_INPUT`` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864.aspx)).

Comment: Chuck Walbourn is right, it's probably a better idea to just use the Win32 message system. I use SDL for its convenience, perhaps you will want look into that. On the other hand I know how annoying it is to be told "no, just use this other library" so I wish you good luck in finding a solution for DirectInput.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys! Right now I'll just stick with DirectInput, because it's working well without the macro. For future project I'll probably search for something more reliable.

Comment: There's some weird ABI bug there - this code being compiled in x86 mode (SysWOW) works on WinXP, but crashes on Win7. But works on Win7 in x64 mode. I've been using this code for years before noticing that!